# Sort pg_dump output

Tags: command-line, diff, postgresql

I have a dump of `pg_dump` before and after an update.

Unfortunately the `COPY` statements are not sorted.

I want to get the dump into a format for easy diffing with the tool "meld".

I could do this with some editing (cut, copy, sort) with my favourite text editor, but an automated tool would be nice.

```
SET statement_timeout = 0;
...


CREATE TABLE table2 (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    cls_id integer NOT NULL,
    activity character varying(4) NOT NULL,
    name character varying(1024) NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE public.table2 OWNER TO postgres;

COPY table2 (id, cls_id, activity, name) FROM stdin;
9130    1309    0005    sun
9131    1309    0006    shining
\.

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(1024) NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE public.table2 OWNER TO postgres;

COPY table2 (id, name) FROM stdin;
1    foo2
2    bar2
\.

-- ...
```

Requirements:

- open source
- command line tool

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called [pgtricks](https://github.com/akaihola/pgtricks) which does this.

From the docs:

pg_dump_splitsort is a handy script for pre-processing PostgreSQL's pg_dump output to make it more suitable for diffing and storing in version control.

```
Usage:

pg_dump_splitsort <filename>.sql

The script splits the dump into the following files:
0000_prologue.sql: everything up to the first COPY
0001_<schema>.<table>.sql
:
:
NNNN_<schema>.<table>.sql: COPY data for each table sorted by the first field
9999_epilogue.sql: everything after the last COPY
```

If you have `pip` installed, you can installed it using

```
pip install pgtricks
```